# What are the solutions of $x^2+1=0$ over the finite field $F$ with ${\rm char}~F\neq 2$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

What are the solutions of $x^2+1=0$ over the finite field $F$ with ${\rm char}~F\neq 2$?
As we know that the solutions of $x^2+1=0$ are $\pm i$ over the complex field, then how about when over the finite field $F$ with ${\rm char}~F\neq 2$? I have no idea, if we should consider field extension? Can someone give me some prompts? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show that the solutions of $x^2 + 1$, if they exist, are precisely the elements of order exactly $4$ in the multiplicative group $F^{\times}$. Now think about when this group has an element of order $4$.

Comment: The congruence $x^ 2 ≡ − 1 \bmod p$   is solvable if and only if $ p \equiv1 \bmod 4$.

Comment: In a situation like this you can also always just try small examples. Check by hand whether there are any such elements in $\mathbb{F}_3, \mathbb{F}_5$, etc. and see what happens.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner $F$ could have order $p^n$.

Comment: I agree, @RobertShore

Comment: You should know that the multiplicative group of $F$ is cyclic of order $p^n-1$. Combine this with Qiaochu's hint. Remember Lagrange and other basic facts about (cyclic) groups.

Comment: If $p\equiv1\pmod4$ it is a nice exercise to show that the solutions of $x^2+1=0$ in $\Bbb{F}_p$ are
$$x=\pm ((p-1)/2)!.$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $\Bbb{F}$ be a finite field with odd characteristic $\operatorname{char}(\Bbb{F}) = p > 2$. $\Bbb{F}$ contains the field with $p$ elements $\Bbb{F}_p$ and is equal to $\Bbb{F}_{p^k}$ for some $k \geq 1$. There are two relevant cases:

- $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$: In this case, $x^2 + 1$ factors over $\Bbb{F}_p$ (this is [a more or less classical result](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares)) and therefore also factors over $\Bbb{F}$. So, $\Bbb{F}$ already contains solutions to $x^2 + 1 = 0$.
- $p \equiv 3 \pmod 4$: In this case, $x^2 + 1$ is irreducible over $\Bbb{F}_p$ ([for the same reason as above](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares)). The splitting field of $x^2 + 1$ over $\Bbb{F}_p$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb{F}_{p^2}$, as it has dimension $2$ as a vector space over $\Bbb{F}_p$ (we can consider it as the quotient $\Bbb{F}_p[x]/(x^2 + 1)$). Since $\Bbb{F}_{p^m} \subseteq \Bbb{F}_{p^n}$ iff $m$ divides $n$,
  this means our original field $\Bbb{F} = \Bbb{F}_{p^k}$ either
  contains a solution of $x^2 + 1 = 0$ (when $k$ is even) or has a degree $2$ extension $\Bbb{F}(i) \cong \Bbb{F}[x]/(x^2 + 1)$ (when $k$ is odd).

Notice that telling you *when* $\Bbb{F} = \Bbb{F}_{p^k}$ contains a root of $x^2 + 1 = 0$ is different than telling you *what that root is in terms of* $p^k$. Indeed, if I were able to do this for every $p$ and every $k$, I would in particular be able to give a positive or negative answer to [Landau's fourth problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau%27s_problems#Near-square_primes): is $n^2 + 1$ prime for infinitely many $n$? (*I would just check if the solution to $x^2 + 1 = 0$ mod $p$, $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, was equal to $\sqrt{p-1}$ infinitely often.*)

Comment: The early parts of the answer are, of course, on the money. I'm afraid you lost me with the connection to Landau's 4th. It is a standard exercise, using Wilson's theorem, that $((p-1)/2)!$ is a solution of $x^2+1\equiv0\pmod p$ when $p\equiv1\pmod4$. Probably that is useless for the purposes of the line of attack you outlined.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yeah, it's weird, because that is both "an explicit formula", and one that's not actually quite explicit *enough* to be useful in solving Landau's fourth problem. Of course, using Wilson's theorem lets us write down several "explicit formulas" for primes, or the prime counting function, that are of little practical use: $$$$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formula_for_primes#Formula_based_on_Wilson's_theorem
$$$$ https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeFormulas.html $$$$ https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeCountingFunction.html

Comment: Nice resources :-)

Comment: Thank you very much!